# TypeScript based template for creating Alexa Smart Home skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there a template for creating an **Alexa Smart Home** skill using TypeScript? There is a [sample project on Github](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-smarthome-switch) that uses Node.js, but it is based on JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't found an official amazon template.
Just this [explanation](https://martinabrahams.com/2018/06/03/writing-alexa-skills-in-typescript-using-skills-sdk-v2/) with this [repo](https://github.com/martinabrahams/alexa-ask-sdk-typescript-boilerplate) for it.

Even if there is no official template or example skill at least you can switch the [code samples](https://developer.amazon.com/de-DE/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/develop-your-first-skill.html) to typescript.

Comment: Thanks for the blog reference. All the ones I have come across, including this, relate to custom skills. It looks like there are no type definitions for smart home skills. `Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()` led me to look for other models under `node_modules` but I could not find any. Looks like migrating from JS to Typescript is the only option for now.

Comment: ah you are right. You explicit asked for smart home skills. If you will make a public repo or at least from the skeleton maybe you could post it here.

Comment: Yes, I will definitely reference any progress I make, on here.